# backup and restore whole disk

Tags: backup, gpt, mbr

I am using iMac, with `GPT` and `Hybrid MBR` partition table.

the GPT layout is:

1. EFI partition.(FAT32)
2. Windows 7 partition.(NTFS)
3. MacOS partition.(HFS+)
4. Linux.(ext4)
5. data.(exfat)

the hybrid MBR is made by `gdisk`, chosen #(1,2,3,5) from GPT.
I have triple boot OS managed by `refind`.

Now, I'd like to backup my whole 500G disk by booting from a external linux USB disk.

I not sure about [GPT table backup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87650/how-do-i-backup-my-partition-table)

Does above link mentioned also backup hybrid MBR?
Or I need to backup GPT and hybrid MBR separately?

To backup, if I booted from Linux USB stick, mounting all partitions.
Then, use `tar jcf` to compress all partition data to another USB hard disk.
say, `efi.tar.bz2`, `win.tar.bz2`, `macos.tar.bz2`, `linux.tar.bz2`, `data.tar.bz2`

To restore, the steps will be, boot from Linux USB stick

1. restore partition table(GPT+Hybrid MBR)
2. reboot and format 5 partitions.
3. mount all partition and `tar xf` above tarballs into mounted path separately.

Is above plan doable? Or any easier way to backup/restore my who disk with compressing ration.
(I don't want to dd my disk...)

Comment: If your disk is named `/dev/sda` under linux and you want just the whole image of your disk, i think you can use: `dd if=/dev/sda | xz > /yourbackup.img.xz` but to restore it you will need a disk with the same geometry (i think)

Comment: Use a "live" CD/USB of Clonezilla.   http://clonezilla.org/